# Using sapply on a function of two variables

Tags: r

I have a list of arrays called l.array that I want to apply a function, Indicator over. Indicator takes in two inputs, an array, and a name. Indicator then makes a new vector with 1 corresponding to a certain input (which input it is depends on the name) in the column corresponding to the name, and 0 corresponding to all other inputs. It then calculates the weighted mean of that vector with some third vector.

How can I pass the Indicator function two variables inside sapply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to write down @James's comment as an answer: If you have the first input in `l.array` and the second input (list of names) as `l.names`, you can do the following with `mapply`:

```
mapply(FUN=Indicator, l.array, l.names)
```

Comment: The main trouble I had was that I only had one name. But I had forgotten that if the length of your vector is a factor of the length of the other vector it repeats so it all works out now. Thanks